# Cannot extract .tar.gz archive in bash

Tags: bash, tar, gzip

I am in my /w dir and I saved the .tar.gz archive from the MediaWiki server like this:

```
$ cd /public_html/w 
$ wget releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.24/mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz
```

But once I try to extract it:

```
$ tar -xvzf mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz
```

It extract to one point and then it stops, I get an error: `-bash: tar: cannot reach server`

How to extract it?

EDIT:

`tar --version`:

```
tar (GNU tar) 1.23
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
```

`file -zi mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz`:

```
mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz: cannot open `mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz' (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: tar should never try to reach a server.. you have something funny going on there.

Comment: Well what can I do to extract the file? I can't even delete it with `$ rm` :(

Comment: type `file mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz`   what does it show it is, what are the perms?

Comment: Post output of `id; cd /public_html/w; pwd; ls -ld .; ls -lZ mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz`

Comment: `file mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz
mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Wed Dec 17 20:17:29 2014, max compression`

Comment: What's the output of `which tar`, `tar --version` and `file -zi mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz ` ?

Comment: @Xavier Lucas see answer.

Comment: Maybe you had to begin with "http://" this url giving to the wget?

Comment: @PowerUser Post the output of `which tar` as requested. Also, make sure you use the correct archive path with the `file` command.

Comment: Is /public_html on some sort of exotic filesystem? As others have said, there is nothing in tar that should say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you try to unzip and untar in separate steps:

```
gunzip mediawiki-1.24.1.tar.gz
```

This will create the file `mediawiki-1.24.1.tar`, and then untar with:

```
tar xvf mediawiki-1.24.1.tar
```

Is that better?